# How to get user rights AND privileges of a Windows User account

Tags: c++, windows, privileges, access-rights

I need to be able to check for all of [these](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349804(v=WS.10).aspx) user rights and privileges.

I have attempted using a token to access these, but this only accomplishes the list of privileges.  I've checked [this library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and also [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375742(v=vs.85).aspx) but am unable to find a solution.  Is the only way to accomplish this testing each specified right / privilege independently?  Or I may just be clueless.

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: The access rights to files are stored with the file, not the user account. You'd have to enumerate all files, basically. So, is this an XY question? Why would you need this?

Comment: For example, SeLogonRight, is not retrievable through a on access token, as it is a right and not a privilege.  Using a access token is the only way I can think of doing this, so I don't know how to check if this right is enabled for the user.  I'm not sure which right you are referring to in the list..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the only way to do this is to use either [`LsaEnumerateAccountsWithUserRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`LsaEnumerateAccountRights`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721790%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to query the LSA policy.

Since rights need not be assigned directly (i.e., they could be assigned to a group, or to a security primitive such as `Everyone` or `INTERACTIVE USERS`) you'll need to enumerate the SIDs in the user's token and cross-reference this with the LSA policy.

Comment: But what if there is a group within a group? Does one have to recursively traverse these?

Comment: @zespri: not if you have a user token to work with, because that already includes all the nested groups.  If you have nothing but a username then you would need to do the recursion yourself.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, understood. Thank you, appreciate the answer